# Wildcard in named ranged that start with the same string

Tags: excel

I have an Excel file with several sheets and in each one, there is a range called as follow: cellRange_*, where * is a number that changes from sheet to sheet.

I'm doing a vba script that pretends to search into the file and retrieve the content to the range into a list, and the code is the following:

```
Cells(iRow, 2).Value = theSheet.Range("cellRange_*")
```

If I write the number in the text, the code works, if I use a variable and give it a number (the specific number) it also works, but the problem is that I can never know which is the specific number in advance. Does anybody know if the wildcards can be used in some other way? Thanks in advance.

Comment: for each name in names

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
Dim name As Variant
For Each name In ThisWorkbook.Names
    If name Like "cellRange_*" Then
        '--- do something interesting now
    End If
Next name
```

Comment: Well, your code doesn't give me an error, this is good. But it doesn't really do anything interesting. I coded to write the name in a cell, but it doesn't do anything. I have to check deeply. Thanks.

Comment: I noticed that your code gives me the address of the range in the variable name, but not the range name. ie: C$9$. In this case I cannot compare it with a text like "cellRange_*". Am I doing something wrong?